# Pass array index into children entries with jq

Tags: jq

If you think the title of this post is off, so do I. I'm happy to reformulate but it's hard to explain.

Given this:

```json
[
  {
    "A": "a",
    "B": "b",
    "C": "c"
  },
  {
    "D": "d",
    "E": "e"
  }
]
```

I want this:

```json
[
 { index: 0, key: "A", value: "a" },
 { index: 0, key: "B", value: "b" },
 { index: 0, key: "C", value: "c" },
 { index: 1, key: "D", value: "d" },
 { index: 1, key: "E", value: "e" }
]
```

Now whether it's a single array in the end or something else, it doesn't really matter.
What I'm really looking for is to **transform** those elements in the input array into key-value pairs, and **add the index** of that element from the array.
So the first object in the array is "index: 0", second is "index: 1", etc.

I can get the index from the array just fine:

```
jq 'to_entries | .[]' sample.json
```

which gives me:

```json
{
  "key": 0,
  "value": {
    "A": "a",
    "B": "b",
    "C": "c"
  }
}
{
  "key": 1,
  "value": {
    "D": "d",
    "E": "e"
  }
}
```

And I can get the key-value pairs just fine too:

```
jq 'to_entries | .[] | .value | to_entries' sample.json
```

which gives me:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "A",
    "value": "a"
  },
  {
    "key": "B",
    "value": "b"
  },
  {
    "key": "C",
    "value": "c"
  }
]
[
  {
    "key": "D",
    "value": "d"
  },
  {
    "key": "E",
    "value": "e"
  }
]
```

but I can't figure out how to combine the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives expected result :

```
jq 'to_entries|map({index:.key}+(.value|to_entries[]))' sample.json
```